# How to block curl or file_get_contents

Tags: php, .htaccess, curl, file-get-contents

How can I disallow someone from using `curl` or `file_get_contents` to get my page HTML?

For example, my domain is `www.example.com`. If someone has PHP code like this:

```
<?php
$info = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/theinfo.php');
?>
```

how can I block them?

I can try to check by the user agent, but that’s not the right way.

What is the best way to check when someone is trying to get the page content?

What I built contains information that many will try to copy to their own websites, and it can overload my server.

Answer (score 1):

> i can try to check it by user agent but its not the right way.

The user agent can indeed be changed through curl but that's pretty much the only way you can tell if someone is accessing your site through curl or not. There's nothing else that's part of the request that distinguishes between them.

That being said, you *could* try to look for some missing fields, as file_get_contents() by default leaves out a bunch of them:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} ^$
RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]
```

though you do run the slight risk of hitting false negatives.

Comment: Thanks, i will look for other ways to check when the user not using browser and if i find anything i will update my question with an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about anyone, not a specific IP or domain, taking your content, you should implement some kind of registration process for your site. Using Apache to filter will probably cause more problems than it is worth. You should ask yourself if what you are putting on the internet is not actually meant for every man and machine out there to do as they please, it should either be login protected or not on the internet.

Here is a very simple to use PHP library for implementing a login and/or registration system:
https://github.com/panique/php-login

Comment: Thanks, but anyone can create new user and then use curl to login :/

Answer (score 0):

Use .htaccess with the corresponding IP address of the site (example.com).
Paste this code in your .htaccess:

```
order allow,deny
deny from 123.45.67.89
allow from all
```

Comment: Thanks, i checked it (from other server) and the file_get_contents() returns my html code.

Comment: Wouldn't this only block requests sent *from* the server that hosts the site? And not all the curl stuff from the rest of the internet?

Comment: @4sha no, it's not bloking any request, i tried to get my page content by free hosting service and file_get_contents returns my html.note:
i think that the answer is on the client side(curl or get_file_contents is not browsers they cant display images :) now i got the idea ;) ).