# Block file_get_content blocks the google bot?

Tags: php, .htaccess, googlebot

I see this; [how to block curl or file_get_contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814509/how-to-block-curl-or-file-get-contents), page of this site. The code is for `.htaccess` for blocking the `file_get_contents` of php.

```
RewriteEngine  On 
RewriteCond%  {HTTP_USER_AGENT}  ^ $ [OR] 
RewriteCond%  {HTTP_ACCEPT}  ^ $
RewriteRule  ^  -  [L, F]
```

My question is What is the possibility of blocking the google bot too?

Comment: This really won't protect anything on your site

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Block All Bots Inluding Google Bot, and All Other Bots With Htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35774742/how-to-block-all-bots-inluding-google-bot-and-all-other-bots-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test it out by going into your [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) account and [fetching a page on your site as Googlebot](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?rd=1). That would be a definitive test.

But it looks like that code is blocking user agents that have no value. Google always identifies itself as Googlebot. It also provides a value for the `v` HTTP header. So I think you'd be fine.