# How to Block All Bots Inluding Google Bot, and All Other Bots With Htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, bots

How can i block all Bots with htaccess. All bots means all Bots, Not even Google or any Bot Should Access My Site.
I am Using custom index.html Page in my site, and in back-end Wordpress is also installed.

Comment: You can block all the good bots but you cant block all the bad bots as you have no way of working out what the difference is between a bad bot and a human. Best you can do is lock the site with htaccess password or restrict it by ip.

Comment: can you give code for block all known bots?

Comment: For all (good) bots now and in the future that obey the robots.txt "standard", then you should use a robots.txt file. Compliant bots then won't even make a request to your site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to ban all, but you could ban some well known ones. To block Google, Yandex, and other well known search engines, check their documentation, or add HTML robots NOINDEX, nofollow meta tag.

For Google check [Googlebots bot doc](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en) they have. Or simply add Google bots:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Googlebot [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mediapartners [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^AdsBot [OR]
```

For .htaccess you will have a long list like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BlackWidow [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Bot\ mailto:craftbot@yahoo.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ChinaClaw [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Custo [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^DISCo [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Download\ Demon [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^eCatch [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EirGrabber [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailSiphon [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailWolf [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Express\ WebPictures [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ExtractorPro [OR]
#... more entries, not showing you the whole list
# as it may contain false positives, find them yourself.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Sucker [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebAuto [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebCopier [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebFetch [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebGo\ IS [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebLeacher [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebReaper [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebSauger [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ eXtractor [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ Quester [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebStripper [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebWhacker [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebZIP [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Wget [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Widow [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WWWOFFLE [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Xaldon\ WebSpider [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Zeus
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Find the list you want, or check bots pages to see what params they are setting. I found this setting from one of the applications I am running.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. But there is no code of Googlebot in your Answer? why?

Comment: I showed you the way how to do that, the rest is on you. For google: see page I gave you, add those bots

Comment: Thanks a Lot bro. you made my Day.